# Pygame: Не работают звуки на Linux

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, аудио, pygame

Столкнулся с проблемой, что звук не воспроизводиться. Решил протестить отдельно и понял, что на Mac os всё нормально, но на Linux (Ubuntu) звука нет. Может кто сталкивался с такой проблемой?

```
import pygame

pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.init()

pygame.display.set_mode((600, 400))

jump_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound('jump.ogg')

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                jump_sound.play()
```

Comment: а сам файл со звуком воспроизводится?

Comment: @KoVadim да, воспроизводится

Comment: метод [play](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.Sound.play) возвращает объект. думаю, он содержит что то полезное.  Но я не исключаю варианта, что просто не может файл найти

Comment: @KoVadim не, файл находит, иначе бы ошибку выдавал. На счёт play: на маке всё ок, поэтому не уверен, что в этом проблема, но посмотрю, что можно ещё с ним сделать

Comment: А вы громкость-то в миксере выставили?

Comment: @0andriy так по дефолту стоит максимальная. Но вообще пробовал и руками ставить. Не помогло :(

Comment: Также гугление показывает, что народ вначале зовёт `pygame.init()`. https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/85967/pygame-error-no-available-audio-device, ну и я всё-таки убедился бы в громкости (запустите параллельно в терминале `alsamixer`).

Comment: @0andriy поменял местами - ничего не изменилось. На счёт alsamixer: не совсем разбираюсь в нём, как он может помочь? Также поставил jump_sound.set_volume(1). Ничего нового

Comment: Ну, попробуйте указать устройство явно `pygame.mixer.init(devicename=...)`, может у вас там их два, и он выбирает какое-то dummy или не то, которое у вас есть с наушниками. В общем запуск `alsamixer` должен показать всё это.

Comment: @0andriy карта - HDA Intel PCH. pygame.mixer.init(devicename='HDA Intel PCH.') сделал. Не помогло

Comment: И что, никаких исключений? Всё тихо? Что-то у вас там не то. В общем, удачи!

Comment: попробуйте pavucontrol

Comment: @694201970 если запускать его вместе с пайчармом, то появляется ошибка pygame.error: No available audio device